# Developing car model with the help of a blueprint

Tags: licensing, blender, 3d-modelling, blueprint

I have taken a car blueprint from the Net(googled)to develop car modeling in Belnder 3d. my question is there any concerns/issues related to copyright/licence ? for example if i want model a AUDI A6, getting the blueprint from the internet, will the AUDI people have some rights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a developer on a rally game a few years past, and from what I recall we had to negotiate licenses with pretty much everyone. And we developed the cars from blueprints, screenshot and those sorts of things. Car manufacturers don't give you a ready made model for your game :)

They were, however, pretty easy to deal with. It all depends if they like the kind of exposure you give them or not. Easiest and safest option would be to send them an email and ask. Avoids any nasty surprises down the road.